# Observable collection in MVVMLIght doesn't upadate UI

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a ViewModel extending Galasoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase. In it i have this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Association> Delegation { get; set; }

    private async void LoadDelegations()
    {
        Delegation.Clear();
        var delegations = await NetworkManager.GetDelegations();
        if(delegations== null)
        {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0;i< delegations.Count;i++)
        {
            Delegation.Add(delegations[i]);
        }
    }

    private async void RemoveDelegation(string delegationId)
    {
        var response = await NetworkManager.RemoveDelegation(delegationId);
        if (response.Result)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < Delegation.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Delegation[i].Id == delegationId) break;
            }

            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Delegation.RemoveAt(i);
            });
        }
    }
```

This property is bound to a ListView:

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AssociationTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Delegation}"/>
```

My problem is that LoadDelegation update the UI only sometimes, instead the RemoveDelegation never update the UI.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you are creating the collection. You may be creating it after the binding had executed, so you need to issue a PropertyChanged event to notify the UI. (I'm not familiar with Galasoft.MvvmLight though.)

Comment: Why would you need (want) a Dispatcher.RunAsync in an `async void` method?  Something doesn't smell right.

Comment: I create the Collection in ViewModel constructor.
Dispatcher.RunAsync allows that instruction to run on UI Thread, doesn't it?

Comment: But a constructor should run on the GUI thread too...  And the RunAsync is in the Remove method. Start by making your async/void exception-safe, and make sure you know when they fail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the MVVM-Light procedure but in the MVVM pattern, The issue here would be that you are using auto-implemented property. So the auto-implemented properties do not raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. You can simply change the Auto-Implemented property of Delegation. You can change it to a full property by `private ObservableCollection delegation;

```
    public ObservableCollection<Association> Delegation
    {
        get { return delegation; }
        set { delegation = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Delegation")}
    }`
```

While `RaisePropertyChanged` is the method that's called as soon as the property changes and lets the view know about it. And as MVVM-Light simply provides the base class which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface